# Check Member of an Associative array In PHP

Tags: php

I created an array as follows.

```
<?php
$Users = [
"user1" => [
    "UserName" => "Ahabiby" ,
    "Password" => "12345678"
],
"user2" => [
    "UserName" => "admin" ,
    "Password" => "admin"
],
"user3" => [
    "UserName" => "MohammadQ" ,
    "Password" => "z12345678"
],
"user4" => [
    "UserName" => "sobhan" ,
    "Password" => "mz1235"
],
"user5" => [
    "UserName" => "ewqfw" ,
    "Password" => "qwscwcqq"
],
"user6" => [
    "UserName" => "adminKoskesh" ,
    "Password" => "UWOEIW"
]
];
```

My problem is how to create a structure when the two variables $username and $password are given to this structure in the array, first compare the $username completely with the "UserName" line in the array, and if there is a $password, compare it with the "Password" values in the array. Also check if the inputs are $username and $password if they were not in the array at all.

I wrote the code snippet myself, but it does not work perfectly because I do not want to add a feature that compares the inputs in the array if they are not complete.

```
<?php
    $username = "MohammadQ";
    $password = "z12345678";
    foreach(array_column($Users,"UserName") as $key){
        if($username == $key){
            foreach(array_column($Users,"Password") as $key){
                if($password == $key){
                    echo "Bingo!";
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: eek use a database, or array_search https://3v4l.org/SWYHZ

Comment: What does this mean exactly _Also check if the inputs are $username and $password if they were not in the array at all._?

Comment: Once it's found a user, your snippet checks every password in the list. It's possible to pass the test with a username and **any** of the passwords, rather than just the password associated with the user.

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to validate using `array_filter` and `closure`

```
    $credentials = array("sobhan", "mz1235");
    $matches = array_filter($Users, function($a) use ($credentials) {
    return $a['UserName'] == $credentials[0] && $a['Password'] == $credentials[1];
    });
    
    $validUser = count($matches)>0 ;
```

Comment: Might want to show how you can get `$username` and `$password` into that function instead of hardcoding the values.

Answer (score 0):

The array structure is not the best, but if you can't change it;  you can index the array on `UserName` with `Password` as the value.

```
$Users = array_column($Users, "Password", "UserName");

if(isset($Users[$username]) && $Users[$username] == $password) {
    echo "Bingo!";
} else {
    echo "NO!!!";
}
```

I'm not totally sure what *Also check if the inputs are $username and $password if they were not in the array at all* means, but maybe:

```
$Users = array_column($Users, "Password", "UserName");

if(isset($Users[$username])) {
    if($Users[$username] == $password) {
        echo "Bingo!";
    } else {
        echo "Bad password!!!";
    }
} else {
    echo "Unknown username!!!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This only needs to be a simple array scan with `foreach`:

```
foreach($Users as $user){
    if ($username === $user['UserName'] && ($user['Password']===$password)) {
        exit('Bingo!');
    }
}
exit('Failed');

See https://3v4l.org/jXeQX
```